# Update object field if it doesn't exist in a list of objects?

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 list of objects that look like this:

```
public class Object1
{
    public string Value1 {get; set;}
    public string Value2 {get; set;}
    public bool Exclude {get; set;}
}
```

And a second one that contains the values that I want to use to exclude values from the first object.

```
public class Object2
{
    public string Value1 {get; set;}
    public string Value2 {get; set;}

}
```

How can I write something that would set the value of Exclude to true if both Value1 and Value2 don't match both of the properties in Object2 concurrently?

```
List<Object1> object1 = new List<Object1>();
List<Object2> object2 = new List<Object2>();
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. There are many previous related questions on SO

Comment: do you mean you want to compare both value fields of an `object1` object to any `object2` object, or you only care if both value fields of an `object1` exist in *any* `object2` (but not necessarily the same one)?

Comment: Do you mean "don't match any of the **properties** in Object2"?

Comment: @LewsTherin yes that's what I meant.

Comment: When you say, *"if both Value1 and Value2 don't match **any** of the properties in Object2"* of the properties, does that mean you would consider `obj1.Value1 = "a"` a match with `obj2.Value2 = "a"`? Or are you only comparing `Value1` with `Value1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
if(!listOfObject2.Any(x => x.Value1 == object1.Value1 
                        && x.Value2 == object1.Value2)
)
{
    object1.Exclude = true;
}
```

In the above snippet, `listOfObject2` is of type `List<Object2>` and `object1` of type `Object1`.

Comment: `object1.Exclude = !listOfObject2.Any(x => x.Value1 == object1.Value1 && x.Value2 == object1.Value2);`

Comment: Actually, I would also change the lambda variable name to make this even clearer: `object1.Exclude = !listOfObject2.Any(object2 => object1.Value1 == object2.Value1 && object1.Value2 == object2.Value2);`

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking to do is mark the objects from the first list for exclusion because there is no object that matches Value1 and Value2 properties in the second list, you can try a `ForEach`:

```
object1.ForEach(o1 => o1.Exclude = !object2.Any(o2 => o2.Value1 == o1.Value1 && o2.Value2 == o1.Value2));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two lists, this should work:

```
foreach (var obj1 in object1)
{
    obj1.Exclude = true;
    foreach (var obj2 in object2)
    {
        if (obj1.Value1.Equals(obj2.Value1)
            || obj1.Value1.Equals(obj2.Value2)
            || obj1.Value2.Equals(obj2.Value1)
            || obj1.Value2.Equals(obj2.Value2))
        {
            obj1.Exclude = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

this will initialize `Exclude` to true, then loop through the `Object1` list and compare both its values to both the values of every `Object2` in the object2 list. If it finds a match, it sets exclude to false and breaks the inner loop because it doesn't need to look anymore. If it makes it all the way through, `Exclude` stays true.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to implement a comparison method on the `Object1` class that takes in an `Object2` and returns `true` if the properties match:

```
public class Object1
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public bool Exclude { get; set; }

    public bool ValuesMatch(Object2 other)
    {
        return (other != null) &&
               Value1 == other.Value1 &&
               Value2 == other.Value2;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this method in your Linq statement:

```
object1.ForEach(o1 => o1.Exclude = object2.Any(o1.ValuesMatch));
```